# You may need an appropriate loader, when upgrading to vue-loader v15

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-loader

I need some help upgrading to vue-loader 15. It seems to think I don't have stylus being loaded, although I believe I have everything loaded correctly
gives this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=stylus (./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/app/app.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=stylus) 71:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (71:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type
| 
| 
> #app
|     display none
|
```

html:

```
<style lang="stylus">
#app
    display none
</style>
```

relevant webpack config:

```
module: {
    rules: [{
    test: /\.styl$/,
    use: [
        'vue-style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        'stylus-loader'
    ]
},
plugins: [new VueLoaderPlugin()]
```

And I have the packages for both stylus and stylus loader installed. I have looked around for a few hours, and it seems most issues are caused by that missing stylus config which I have.

Answer (score 0):

This is my current working setup now:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.styl(us)?$/,
            use: [
                'vue-style-loader',
                'css-loader',
                'stylus-loader'
            ]
        }
    ]
},
plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin()
]
```